# How to loop a function with sapply?

Tags: r, function, sapply

I would like to calculate roots for different y-values of a quadratic equation. But when I run the following code get an error I do not understand. If y is just one numeric value, instead of the vector c(0.6,0.4,0.9), it works. I am using sapply wrongly or is it the passing of variables to the function that are wrong?

```
# Paramters for quadratic poly
a<-0.875
b<-0.3779
c<-0.098
y<- c(0.6,0.4,0.9)

# quadratic function
fun<-function(x) c-y+b*x+a*x^2

# Finding root in specific interval function
root<- function (x) uniroot(fun,c(0,2))$root

# Finding roots for a list of y values
res<-sapply(y,root)
```

Comment: you're not passing your `y` (which becomes `x` in the `root` function) to your inner `fun` function.  FWIW, I get the same error calling `root()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for example :

```
 sapply(y,function(y) uniroot(fun,c(0,2),y=y,c=c,a=a,b=b))
```

Comment: Thanks... This now works. So it was a quastion about passing variables to the function.
# Paramters for quadratic poly
a<-0.875
b<-0.3779
c<-0.098
y<- c(0.8,0.4)

# quadratic function
fun<-function(x,y,a,b,c) c-y+b*x+a*x^2
# Finding root in specific interval 0,2
sapply(y,function(y) uniroot(fun,c(0,2),y=y,c=c,a=a,b=b)$root)